# Contacts no longer open in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, contacts

Contacts on macOS Sierra is not opening anymore. I get the following error:

[image]

If I try to start Contacts from the terminal, I get the following errors:

```
$ /Applications/Contacts.app/Contents/MacOS/Contacts 
CoreData: warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDInfo while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDInfo'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?
CoreData: warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDGroup while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDGroup'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?
CoreData: warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'serialNumber' for entity ABCDAddressBookSource while resolving selector 'serialNumber' on class 'ABCDAddressBookSource'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?
CoreData: warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDAddressBookSource while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDAddressBookSource'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?
CoreData: warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDContact while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDContact'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?
CoreData: warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'imageReference' for entity ABCDContact while resolving selector 'imageReference' on class 'ABCDContact'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?
```

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?